# porting pdf.js example to electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to recreate the previous/next example from:
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/

as an Electron app. I've copied the main part of the html into my Electron index file. `renderer.js` is essentially the javascript file on the example page.

Now I've tried to make the following changes:

1. I ran `npm install webpack` as it is a peer dependency for pdfjs
2. ran `npm install pdfjs-dist`

Note I'm not sure if I should have done `pdfjs-dist` or `pdfjs`

Then in the script I replaced:

```
var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];`
```

with

```
var pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs');
```

But importantly, I wasn't sure how to handle the worker line:

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

For reasons that are unclear to me, this line gets resolved to `file://mozilla ...` so I manually changed it to https://

```
    pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = 'https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';
```

Unfortunately now I get an error about a promise and trying to get numPages on a null object. This is the offending code:

```
/**
 * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
 */
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

  // Initial/first page rendering
  renderPage(pageNum);
});
```

So the questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Bonus: is pdfjs-dist the best option? How in general would I link something like .js to the npm install?
3. Bonus: How do I get the worker to not rely on the website?

Answer (score 0):

in case you're still looking for a solution, I got it to work using

```
pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = './node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js'
```

pdfjs-dist folder inside node-modules has the build files